# How do I keep focus on TextBox after a button was pushed?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a XAML ListBox, a TextBox inside the ItemTemplate. A user edits text inside the TextBox, and then presses a button in the application bar. How do I keep the focus on the TextBox after the button in the application bar was pushed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. You set it back afterwards.

You can use `Focus()` method to do this.

You can also use the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` to highlight a specific part of the text.

Comment: Would you happen to have some code samples on how I get to a TextBox after the items have been re-bound to it?

Comment: @Eugene not sure what you mean. Try asking it as another question with examples/details of what you're trying to do